# I do not OR I not

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In the below sentences, ***do*** is not present.

> My doctor insists that I (***do***) not eat donuts with chocolate sauce and hamburger patties for breakfast.
>
> It's imperative you (***do***) not sing when your voice hurts.

Why is the ***do*** not present in the sentences?
Which grammatical rule would be violated if ***do*** is included in the sentences?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. While both questions are about the subjunctive, the other question does not address negation.

Comment: @phenry Why do think negation matters?

Comment: Because the leap from understanding the role of uninflected verbs in the subjunctive to knowing when to drop "do" is a non-intuitive one.

Answer (score 0):

This missing words are *implied:*

"It's imperative {that} you {do} not sing when your voice hurts."

This can further be simplified into a command:

"Do not sing when your voice hurts."

Comment: That’s not really what’s happening here. He just doesn’t understand the subjunctive.